# How to add array to a specific object in a data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here how I'm trying to add some values to my data. The problem is that the tasks add as an object in the same level as parent's object. Like this: [image]

However, I need it to be inside an object.

```
// This is my data
const [list, setList] = useState({
        home: {
          title: "Home",
          color: "#5786ff",
          icon: <MdContentPaste />,
          tasks: [
            {
              note: "Play Basketball",
              time: "21:00",
            },
          ],
        },
        work: {
          title: "Work",
          color: "#ffc93c",
          icon: <MdMailOutline />,
          tasks: [
            { note: "Write Essay", time: "2:00" },
          ],
        },
      });

// Here I am trying to add the notes to my tasks
const [noteInput, setNoteInput] = useState("");
const [noteTime, setNoteTime] = useState("");
const handleSubmit = () => {
    setList({
      ...list,
      tasks: [...list[listName].tasks, { note: noteInput, time: noteTime }],
    });
  };

// Explanation
(...list[listName].tasks) - takes the parent object's tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listName` looks to be the top level property, so use that to add another level:

```
setList({
      ...list,
      [listName]: {
        ...list[listName],
        tasks: [...list[listName].tasks, { note: noteInput, time: noteTime }],
      },
    });
```